# How to configure In App Notification using MixPanel

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, mixpanel

I have integrated MixPanel in my application and working fine with other trackers and push notifications, But now i want to implement In App Notification. I want to display In App Notification on Payment page of my application to display promo code to user.

I have followed documentation from [MixPanel](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/ios-inapp-notifications), but still not getting notifications.

If any one have implemented MixPanel with In App Notification before then please help me.

Here i am calling `showNotification` method in Payment page's `viewWillAppear:` method.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    //Display In App Notifications
    mixpanel?.showNotification()

}
```

Any help should be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.